# How to open a tmux session in a remote machine using SSHLibrary?

Tags: robotframework, tmux, robotframework-sshlibrary

Failed to create a `tmux` session in a remote machine with SSHLibrary in robot framework.

Code tried -

```
Execute Command   tmux new -s session01
```

Output-

```
   20211213 12:33:37.257 :  INFO : Executing command 'tmux new -s session01'.
   20211213 12:33:37.348 :  INFO : Command exited with return code 1.
```

Comment: You should try to run the test with `--loglevel TRACE` to get better error. I think that there is an option to return full error, not just the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute in the following way -

```
Execute Command   tmux new-session -d -s session_name 'Command To Execute'
```